# FPDF MultiCell Long Text - How to set what page to start

Tags: php, laravel, fpdf

I'm trying to use multicell to print the list of items. It works if item descriptions are short and can fit into 1 page but if it is 2 pages or more, other columns are printing starting at the other pages instead of starting at the same page.

I also tried using this link http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script3.php but it prints to the other page if the description does not fit in the first page.

```
foreach ($particulars as $i => $get) {
$bl = substr_count( $get->description, "\n" );
$item_no = $get->item_no;
$stock_no = $get->stock_no;
$z = 1;
while($z < $bl) {
    $item_no = $item_no."\n";
    $stock_no = $stock_no."\n";
    $z++;
}
$y = $pdf->GetY();
$x = $pdf->GetX();
$pdf->MultiCell(10,5,''.$item_no,1,'L',False);
$pdf->SetXY($x + 35, $y);
$pdf->MultiCell(90,5,''.$get->description,1,'L',False);
```

[Result1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQtZl.png) and [Result2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S52bh.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try storing the page where you're storing the x and y position and resetting the page number (SetPage()) as you loop through the row cells.

Comment: I can't find any example of how to use SetPage(). Can You provide me some?

Comment: Sorry we had added a SetPage() in our implementation. Here's a better response on some of the pitfalls of this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14187714/8643745